# Handling concurrent requests with Warp

Tags: haskell-warp

I have made a Wai web application and it is being run using Warp. However I have one AJAX request that takes quite some time to finish, while that request is pending, no other requests will be accepted by the server. I thought Warp was capable of handling concurrent requests. Am I missing something? The way I run Warp is just by calling `run port app` where `run` is imported via `import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)` and `app` is my Wai application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying [Happstack Lite](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/index.html#your-first-app) to see whether it would solve my problem, and there the `-threaded` flag was used when compiling the web application, which also solved my concurrent requests problem in the Warp application. I was under the assumption that GHC would have threading support by default, but apparently this have to be [specified explicitly during compilation](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html#id674755).